# How to get form/pop-up when we click on 'Save' button?

Tags: python, openerp-7

I am trying to get a form/pop-up when i click on 'Save' button.

How can we do this?

What i tried is:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        global globvar
        globvar = 1
        view_ref = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'cornerstone', 'enroll_program')
        view_id = view_ref and view_ref[1] or False
        return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': _('If required add another Program for Learner'),
        'res_model': 'learner.info',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_id': ids[0], # this will open particular Learner Details,
        'view_id': view_id,
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'nodestroy': True,
        'target':'new',
        }
```

Is there any other method to get pop/up when we click on 'Save' button.

Comment: What kind of `pop/up`. Please give more details.

Comment: It should open another form when we click on 'Save' button. In that form there will be some fields.

Comment: In this code you overwrite `create` method. you shoud call parent method to create. `current_id = super(dossier, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `create` method is an ORM method, and it is not possible to modify an ORM method to make it return a pop-up instead of a recordset. Take a look at this post:

[How to call a wizard from a function in OpenERP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946554/how-to-call-a-wizard-from-a-function-in-openerp7/27959435#27959435)

Comment: Thanks, so any other alternative?

Comment: It's difficult. May be you can hide the original *Create* button, and create your own *Create* button. This one should call a method created by you, for example `create_and_show_popup`. Inside this you should call ORM `create` method and then, instead of return the created record, return the pop-up. I think someone with more knowledge can give you a better answer.